# Use seqel pro connect to AWS RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rds, sequelpro

I was using the AWS free tier to setup my Rails project.

However, I felt confused about why I can't connect `RDS` via `sequel pro`.

Here is the `VPC` `security group` which `RDS` was using.

[image]

I set the same host, username, pwd and database name in my rails `database.yml`.

My Rails project on `EC2` can connent to `RDS` perfectly, but it fails to connect from sequel pro.

Comment: Sanity check: is your RDS instance's `Publicly accessible` setting set to `yes`?

Comment: That's right! How silly I am. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lack of connectivity to RDS instance from outside VPC, while access from VPC works fine is usually related to RDS' DNS name not resolving outside VPC. Set `Publicly accessible` setting of your database to `yes` to be able to connect from outside.

From [AWS docs - Hiding a DB Instance in a VPC from the Internet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Hiding):

> When you launch a DB instance inside a VPC, you can designate whether
>   the DB instance you create has a DNS that resolves to a public IP
>   address by using the PubliclyAccessible parameter. This parameter lets
>   you designate whether there is public access to the DB instance. Note
>   that access to the DB instance is ultimately controlled by the
>   security group it uses, and that public access is not permitted if the
>   security group assigned to the DB instance does not permit it.
>
> You can modify a DB instance to turn on or off public accessibility by
>   modifying the PubliclyAccessible parameter. This parameter is modified
>   just like any other DB instance parameter. For more information, see
>   the modifying section for your DB engine.

**NOTE:** Opening any port in your RDS' security group for `0.0.0.0/0` CIDR range is a dangerous practice. Be specific and set up only source IPs that should be able to connect to your RDS instance in the security group.

Comment: Thanks! it's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having issues with Sequel Pro. The thread below helped me out. I downloaded Sequel Ace and it fixed my SSH + RDS Connection issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56402217/1051391