# Sequel Pro and MySQL connection failed

Tags: mysql, database-connection, sequelpro

I just installed mysql on mac from Homebrew

```
brew install mysql

mysql -V

mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

from terminal it works and I can login to mysql but from Sequel Pro it says

[image]

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.
>
> Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary
>   privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10
>   seconds).
>
> MySQL said: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be
>   loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2):
>   image not found

can't figure out what I am missing

Answer (score 239, accepted):

This is because Sequel Pro is not ready yet for a new kind of user login, as the error states: there is no driver.

### mysql + homebrew

Basically you will have to perform some actions manually, however- your database data won't be deleted like in solution below

- Go to my.cnf file and in section `[mysqld]` add line:

  `default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`
- Login to mysql server from terminal: run `mysql -u root -p`, then inside shell execute this command (replacing *[password]* with your actual password):

  `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '[password]';`
- exit from mysql shell with `exit` and run `brew services restart mysql`.

Should work.

### Quick fix (destructive method)

Quick fix for non-homebrew installs:

`Apple Logo > System Preferences > MySQL > Initialize Database`, then type your new password and select 'Use legacy password'

After restart you should be able to connect. Do it only on fresh installs, because you may lost your db tables otherwise.

---

### my.cnf

The my.cnf file is located in /etc/my.cnf on Unix/Linux

---

### Alternatives

For those who is still struggling with Sequel Pro problems: Sequel Pro was a great product, but with tons of unresolved issues and last release being dated to 2016 perhaps it's a good idea to look for some alternatives. There is a fork of SequelPro called SequelAce that seems to be pretty stable and up-to-date, it keeps similar functionality, similar look and feel, yet at the same time it is devoid of old Sequel Pro problems

Comment: I can't find MySQL in System Preferences

Comment: thanks for explain, but can't locate `my.cnf` file on my machine(macOS High Sierra 10.13.5)

Comment: If there is no such file, you will have to create one: please, have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973927/for-homebrew-mysql-installs-wheres-my-cnf

Comment: I also don't have mysql in my system preferences, and didn't find the my.cnf inside `/etc`, but found it via `$ brew list mysql | grep my.cnf` in `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/.bottle/etc/my.cnf` on macOS and mysql installed via homebrew. Editing it there and then following the commands from this answer solved OPs problem for me which I also faced.

Comment: Hmm... followed the proposed solution. Authentication appears to work, however, now the schema/tables fail to load and a generic "Unexpected error occurred". Issue detailed on the repo here: https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2699

Comment: This worked great on a fresh `brew install mysql` using `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: didnt work for me, after I did that I started getting more errors :( ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Updated my.cnf file, logged into mysql server, command to change password returned `ERROR 1726 (HY000): Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.db]`
A full uninstall en reinstall fixed this for me: https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks

Comment: Is the fault of Sequel Pro? "This is because Sequel Pro is not ready yet for a new kind of user login" sounds pretty vague. Should we use a better client?

Comment: @Jonny at the time of writing the answer none of the clients I knew were able to connect without errors. I don't know how the situation looks like now, but 'better client' question is pretty subjective here, Sequel Pro is a good option and I'm still using it, if you will find better alternative is only up to you.

Comment: I ended up using an older MySQL version in my docker composer so I could stay with Sequel Pro.

Comment: It's a great if you are fine with *changing your car, because you are in love with a tire brand.*  A secure alternative is changing the tire brand you are in love with. See my answer below.

Comment: I didn't use a password, so I used `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';` - this worked for me

Comment: worked for me, just remembering to set it password when connection on your CLI as well (dbeaver, workbench etc...)

Comment: On OSX Mojave, the my.cnf file is at /usr/local/etc/my.cnf

Comment: This worked, however only unintentionally adopting the destructive method, which unfortunately comes first. Let me suggest to flip the order, since, like me, someone can ruin their DB, without being aware of this implication.

Comment: It works for MySQL 8.~ of Homebrew installation on Macbook Air M1. Thanks

Comment: Brilliant! So stupid I did not look at clicking on "Initialize Database". By the way you can also do `FLUSH PRIVILEGES; ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPassword';` and you can access db by doing this: `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop` (or click on "Stop MySQL Server)
You can also check System Preferences > MySQL to see if it is running
Start MySQL with this command:`
`sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
Open a new terminal window/tab:`
`sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51897983/4135524

Comment: but actually with MacOS It worked only by clicking on "Initialise Database" in Mysql (accessible from System settings of Mac settings) and then set as password my new password

Answer (score 74):

TL;DR: Sequel Pro is dead since 2016.  Don't downgrade your DB because of a tool. Move on to an alternative tool.

**Update 2020: Sequel Pro is officially dead but unofficially alive!**  You can find the "*nightly*" builds that don't have this issue (i.e. support Mysql 8 auth) in here: https://sequelpro.com/test-builds

**Update 2021: Sequel Ace** is a good similar alive alternative: https://github.com/Sequel-Ace/Sequel-Ace#installation (Credits to Maciej Kwas's answer)

---

All the other solutions here are recommending changing your DB settings (making it less secure, as advertised by MySQL) for the tool you are using.  That's not acceptable to me.

I have always been a huge fan of Sequel Pro, even donated to it.  But, with all my passion and love, I am sorry if the tool doesn't have any release [since 2016](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/releases).  YOLO, and I need to move on!

The alternative I found (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55235533/2321594, thanks to @arcseldon) is [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/download/) which supports MySQL 8's new authentication (non-legacy) method.

PS. The only trick **in the tool side, not the DB side** is when you are creating a MySQL 8 connection you might need to go to "Driver Properties" (later can be found in Edit Connection) and turn the value of `allowPublicKeyRetrieval` to `true`.

I needed this to connect to my MySQL container created using Docker.  To have the IP of MySQL be visible to the outside, for any other application in your ecosystem (not just this tool), you should either create a new user in MySQL, or pass `-e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%` in the run-time or as an ENV.

Comment: I believe @Aidin you gave me a downvote just because my answer does not resolves the OP problem. It's just a local development and local settings- so what's the point? Do I really have to leave software I am familiar with and I like to work with just because you say so?

Comment: Please don't take it personal @MaciejKwas.  Despite providing more explanation here, which I appreciate, I am still standing by my vote.  The three main reasons are: 1) Maintaining different setup between dev/prod is not recommended in modern software development.  It's, in fact, factor X of https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity . 2) People can use these tools for checking prod as well. You can create a ssh-tunnel/proxy and get to your prod DB via a GUI tool.  In such cases, downgrading the DB auth is not an option.  3) Not adapting to change and upgrade is something I don't value, personally.

Comment: I'm coming back to a MySQL project I haven't ran locally in a couple years b/c it's been rock solid and i'm so sad to find out that sequel pro is dead :(

Comment: Also choose the MySQL +8 driver in DBeaver as there are multiple drivers to choose from. In the driver properties set allowPublicKeyRetrieval to true and save.

Comment: That's a shame because Sequel Pro has a great icon.

Comment: OMG, you made my day with Sequel Ace tip! Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

[Sequel Pro is officially dead](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/3592) and no longer supports newer MySql features. However, the good news is that it was replaced by [Sequel Ace](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/3705) which is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Sequel-Ace/Sequel-Ace) and [App store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/sequel-ace/id1518036000?ls=1). The app is free of charge and looks like official replacement for Sequel Pro as the [post was made by one of the collaborators of Sequel Pro](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/3705).

Ps. I decided to post this as an answer as others have not mentioned that there is now an up-to-date replacement for Sequel Pro

Comment: Thanks for news, much appreciated.

Comment: Finally! Been waiting for a while.

Answer (score 20):

1. Assuming you don't have a **mysql** configuration, echo the following to `~/.my.conf`.

   ```
   [mysqld]
   default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
   ```
2. Sign into **mysql** with `mysql -u root -p`
3. Set the root user password with `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '[PASSWORD]';` where `[PASSWORD]` is a password of your choosing.
4. Restart **mysql** with e.g. `brew services restart mysql`

Comment: It's a great solution if you realllllllllllly don't care about anything and it's just a local, dev, test-only, practice, one-time, throw-away database.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509065 for the explanation of why it's a bad idea to change DB, because of a tool.

Answer (score 6):

If you connect to MySQL via root@127.0.0.1, make sure that you reset its password too!

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '[password]';
```

Comment: I am getting: `ERROR 3009 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 50, found 49. Created with MySQL 80012, now running 80013. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.`

Comment: try this on the terminal:  **mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p**

Comment: mysql_upgrade has now been deprecated and won't work, use mysqld --upgrade=FORCE instead.

Comment: It's a great solution if you realllllllllllly don't care about anything and it's just a local, dev, test-only, practice, one-time, throw-away database.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509065 for the explanation of why it's a bad idea to change DB, because of a tool.

Answer (score 5):

**It's working for me.** if you are getting this error :

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.
>
> Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary
> privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10
> seconds).
>
> MySQL said: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be
> loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2):

*Plz try this solution*

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: It's a great solution if you realllllllllllly don't care about anything and it's just a local, dev, test-only, practice, one-time, throw-away database.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509065 for the explanation of why it's a bad idea to change DB, because of a tool.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone facing this issue and installed MySQL version > 8 through `.dmg` file; downloaded it from the official link. In that case please use [this guideline](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2991#issuecomment-422011734). I am adding the same details below in case the link will not be available in the future.

This issue is because you're using the new `Strong Password Encryption` which is a new feature in MySQL 8, if you installed MySQL 8 using the `.dmg` file, you can go to `System Preferences > MySQL` and then click on `Initialize Database` type your password and select the second option `Use Legacy Password Encryption`.

Comment: Using a old style password worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

My M1 Mac running Ventura 13.5 had my.cnf located `/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf`