# Sequel Pro gives 'Connection failed!' error using Docker Mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, sequelpro

I am unable to connect my Sequel Pro to my docker mysql container. I keep getting the following error message:

[image]

I have a docker-compose.yml ;

```
db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports: 
            - "33071:3306"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=default
        volumes:
            - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - ./db/mysqlconf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
            - ./mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
        
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8677:80"
    links:
      - db
```

I have read multiple forum answers on this but none of them helps. The most relevant is [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179516/sequel-pro-and-mysql-connection-failed) but this seems to relate to the mysql on the mac as opposed to a docker container. He talks of editing the  my.cnf file  located in /etc/my.cnf. on Unix/Linux.

However my docker container does not have a my.cnf file.

So I am not sure what to do.
I used the following settings for Sequel Pro connection:

```
Host:     127.0.0.1
Username: root  
Password: root 
Database: (left it blank)
Port:     3306
```

Answer (score 4):

You are mapping port `33071` of your host, to port `3306` of your docker container in your docker-compose file.

```
ports: 
    - "33071:3306"
```

But in your Sequel Pro settings mentioned above, you are using port `3306` of your host. That is incorrect.

### **Solution:**

> Use the host port that is mapped with docker container i.e **`33071`**
>
> (Ideally you should have kept the port as `3307` in port mapping).

Comment: Why port `3307`?

Comment: Not necessary, I just mentioned that because it is easier to remember. Well it is choice based.

Comment: Why not `3306`?

Comment: So if you are using Docker for mysql, there is a chance that user has already installed mysql server on local(which is on port 3306 of localhost always). So to differentiate, a different port can be used. Depends on the use case.

Comment: If one uses Docker for MySQL, the chances are that they do not have the MySQL server installed and cannot or do not want to install it. Otherwise, why would they use MySQL in a Docker container?

Comment: 1. Requirement of different mysql versions in development.
2. Multiple mysql containers that need to be started simultaneously, so you need different port numbers for them.